# Buscar los NaN de un dataframe y buscar si hay información complementaria en otro dataframe

Tags: python

Tengo dos dataframe con 50.000 observaciones cada uno, ambos con valores NaN.
Quiero:

- averiguar que los valores NaN en uno y en el otro no correspondan a la misma observación (index);
- sustituir los NaN de una columna con la información contenida en la otra columna.

Comment: Saludos, en SO-es no hacemos tareas ni exámenes, por favor agrega el código que has tratado de hacer. ;)

Comment: Buen día, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Es desmotivante entrar en una publicación con la intención de ayudar y ver que el usuario no ha mostrado que ha investigado o intentado algo. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código que tienes hasta el momento y los errores que recibes, o en su defecto mostrar lo que has investigado. El objetivo de este sitio es ayudar a las personas que muestran un esfuerzo por resolver sus propias preguntas. Si la solicitud es del tipo alguien hágalo por mi, tal vez un sitio de `freelance` sea mejor opción.